# Cannot use XeTeXglyph with ptmr8c; not a native platform font

Tags: xetex

After I update my texlive in macOS Catalina 15.03.When I compile my latex book,throw this error:

```
Cannot use XeTeXglyph with ptmr8c; not a native platform font.
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Not possible. `\XeTeXglyph` *never* worked with tfm fonts.  You changed something else than “just update TeX Live”.

Answer (score 0):

I found this may due to the use of the following package:

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts

When I use itemize or listings, the error pops out. So I just comment that line.

when using \item, one may add \item[$\bullet$] to resolve the problem.

Comment: You should never use `fontenc` with the XeLaTeX compiler, this package was made to be used with previous, older compilers anyway.